# В чем преимущества использования SPRING по отношению к J2EE?

Tags: spring, j2ee

Нужен конкретный "плюс" использования в приложении по обработке фотографий технических проблем на производстве именно spring. Что конкретно может spring чего не может j2ee?
В j2ee я использую servlet для маршрутизации, filter для логирования, jsp для отображения, custom tags для валидации и трасформации, jms для коммуникации, stored procedure on db для хранения изобрабражений, pojo для текстовой обертки изображения.
Размещаю все либо на websphere либо на tomcat.
Засем нужен spring?

Comment: https://dou.ua/lenta/articles/javaee-vs-spring/

Comment: Жаль и спасибо. Спасибо за статью. Жаль, что ничего нового в spring нет.

Comment: Перечитывайте значит статью и почитайте отдельно про Spring. У него куча нового по сравнению с J2EE. Концептуально +- тоже самое но гораздо проще удобнее и гибче.